# How to create a GitHub page with a theme?

Tags: html, github, themes, github-pages

I'm trying to create a simple GitHub page following the [official instructions page](https://pages.github.com). I set up the theme in the Settings of my repository which added a `_config.yml` file. However, [my page](https://ivanyurchenko.github.io/fantasyworldsrating/) still looks like a plain HTML:

[image: not working page]

I have tried several different approaches but none of them seem to work.

The links here aren't working for me as well so it might cause the problem, however, I don't know where else I could get the themes in case I need to download them to store locally.

[image: not working links]

Here's a link to my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IvanYurchenko/fantasyworldsrating).

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://pages.github.com/themes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick Cannariato has helped me to make it work. [The problem was](https://github.com/IvanYurchenko/fantasyworldsrating/pull/1) in my `index.html` file.

Instead of this:

```
 -<!DOCTYPE html>
 -<html>
 -    <head>
 -        <meta charset="UTF-8">
 -        <title>Рейтинг книг fantasy-worlds.org</title>
 -    </head>
 -    <body>
 -        <div class="container"></div>
 -    </body>
 -</html>
```

I needed this:

```
 +---
 +layout: default
 +title: Рейтинг книг fantasy-worlds.org
 +---
 +
 +<body>
 +    <div class="container"></div>
 +</body>
```